# A yellow background color with a button

Tags: html, css

I only set up one button and backgroup is yellow, but it shows two area of yellow color. As a image i posted below:
I only need one yellow background under text.

CSS:

```
.button {
margin-left: 121px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 84px;
height: 45px;   
background: yellow;
border: none;
color: white;   
font-size:14px;
font-weight:700;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
<a href="#" class="button">button</a>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You used two same classes for the link and the div button. Assign it to only one element (I guess you want it assigned to the outer div). Also, if you want a button, you should use <input> or <button>.

Comment: Play around: [Example](http://jsbin.com/levayigo/1/edit)